# How do I transform rows with values into a dataframe of stacked value pairs?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not even sure how to write the question, but here's what I'm wondering. I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
# df_1:
Row 1: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Row 2: 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

I want to transform this into a dataframe that looks like this:

```
# df_2:
Row 1: 1, 2
Row 2: 2, 3
Row 3: 3, 4
Row 4: 4, 5
```

...and so on.

Current implementation:

```
a = df_1.iloc[0:, 0:2]
b = df_1.iloc[0:, 1:3]
c = df_1.iloc[0:, 2:4]
d = df_1.iloc[0:, 3:5]

df_list = [a, b, c, d]

df_2 = pd.concat(df_list)
```

This is sucky for obvious reasons.

EDIT: fixed the values in df_1 Row 1

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're asking.  Can you _show_ what your expected output looks like based on the _provided_ sample data? Because currently your input frame has no 4s and your output frame has 2 4s with no explanation for how or why new values are introduced.

Comment: It looks like the `3, 3` is an error and should be `3, 4`. If not, please explain...

Comment: If you run the code on the provided frame `df_1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 3, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]])` you actually end up with `(8, 5)` so... That's why I'm unsure. Because the shown output and the current implementation don't seem compatible either.

Comment: I think that the `loc` column slicing if erroneous on the upper bound. It looks like python slicing with excluded upper bound when probably OP means `0:1` in place of `0:2` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to transform `[a,b,c,d,e]` into `[[a,b],[b,c],[c,d],[d,e]]`: you can do:

```
# example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Row 1': [1, 2, 3, 3, 5],
                   'Row 2': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]}).T
# get first row
r = df.loc['Row 1']
# combine self with shifted to create expected output
pd.DataFrame(zip(r[:-1],r.shift(-1)))
```

or using `numpy.roll`:

```
import numpy as np
r = df.loc['Row 1']
pd.DataFrame(zip(r[:-1],np.roll(r, -1)))
```

input:

```
       0  1  2  3   4
Row 1  1  2  3  3   5
Row 2  6  7  8  9  10
```

output:

```
   0  1
0  1  2
1  2  3
2  3  3
3  3  5
```